# jwplayer: fire google adword or analytic conversion?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

how would you track someone playing a flash video on your website using google adwords/analytics  conversion?

The purpose is to be notified when a visitor views the flash video, and when the visitor finishes viewing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a question about using a plugin to do this on stackoverflow, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968635/2983) says how to do it without any extra software.

Or you can use the [plugin](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/addons/google-analytics-pro/10646/getting-started-with-the-google-analytics-jw-player-plugin).